# Problems with Perl installation wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32

Tags: linux, perl, elf, gnu-parallel, perlbrew

I wanted to run `gnu_parallel` on one of my servers(nproc=48). When I try to run the command,

```
seq 1 5000 | parallel --eta 'echo {} > /dev/null'
```

I was getting some errors,

```
Can't load '/usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/Fcntl/Fcntl.so' for module Fcntl: /usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/Fcntl/Fcntl.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32 at /usr/lib64/perl5/XSLoader.pm line 70.
 at /usr/local/lib64/perl5/Fcntl.pm line 215
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/lib64/perl5/Fcntl.pm line 216.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/lib64/perl5/POSIX.pm line 19.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/lib64/perl5/POSIX.pm line 19.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/bin/parallel line 24.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/parallel line 24.
```

I don’t want to re-install Perl on the server as there are many servers using it.

I can do anything which will not harm current applications running on my servers.

Please tell me a way to run parallel.

```
OS: Cent-OS 6.4  64 bit
nproc: 48
RAM: 512 GB
```

**EDIT:**

Else Will I be able to use App::Fatpacker ? for solving the issue ?

**EDIT 2**

I tried and failed using Fatpacker.

**EDIT: 3**
I tried Installing perlbrew: got following errors of wrong ELFClASS

```
    Can't load '/usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/PerlIO/scalar/scalar.so' for module PerlIO::scalar: /usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/PerlIO/scalar/scalar.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32 at /usr/lib64/perl5/XSLoader.pm line 70.
 at /usr/local/lib64/perl5/PerlIO/scalar.pm line 4
Compilation failed in require at (eval 1) line 3.
FatPacker error loading App/perlbrew.pm (could be a perl installation issue?) at perlbrew-23345 line 551.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at perlbrew-23345 line 562.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a new installation of perl in a different directory by following,

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/perl5142
sudo chown $USER:$USER /usr/local/perl5142
cd /usr/local/perl5142/
mkdir build cpan
cd build/
wget http://www.cpan.org/src/perl-5.14.2.tar.gz
tar xzvf perl-5.14.2.tar.gz
cd perl-5.14.2
rm -f config.sh Policy.sh ; sh Configure -de -Dprefix=/usr/local/perl5142
make && make test && make install
```

Source: [Instructions for multiple perl installations](http://troy.jdmz.net/perls/)

For makinng the parallel to use this new installation I've edited the shebang line of the parallel from `#!/usr/bin/env perl` to `#! /usr/local/perl5142/build/perl-5.14.2/perl`.

No harm done to any of the  existing installations and Parallel is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

`Can't load '/usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/Fcntl/Fcntl.so' for module Fcntl: /usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/Fcntl/Fcntl.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32 at /usr/lib64/perl5/XSLoader.pm line 70.`

It seems that `/usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/Fcntl/Fcntl.so` is 32-bit.

try file command :
`file /usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/Fcntl/Fcntl.so`

Comment: /usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/Fcntl/Fcntl.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped

Comment: As file shows: `/usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/Fcntl/Fcntl.so` is 32-bit. Strangely, why 32-bit library located in lib64/?

Comment: What should I do know ? Fixable problem ?

Comment: @aravindramesh  You may install some 32-bit modules in your server, but perl is 64-bit. So check the installation of perl modules, and install the 64-bit one!  The problem will be fixed!

Comment: Please elaborate. What should I install.

Comment: @aravindramesh  You can also reinstall perl to a **different path**, and let parallel use it!  This will not harm any current applications!

Comment: @aravindramesh  Sorry, I know little about perl, may be you can try **reinstall perl**

Comment: I do not want do that. It might cause problems with existing applications.

Comment: @aravindramesh  **reinstall perl to a different path** it have nothing to do with existing applications, just let parallel use the new perl.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50031/discussion-between-aravind-ramesh-and-fhvrrt)

Comment: Re "It might cause problems with existing applications.", It's true that it might cause problems. On the other hand, your broken Perl installation is currently definitely causing real problems.

Comment: @ikegami I dont know how but they are running smoothly. I need a altenative to this problem.

Comment: Running smoothly? That's great! How did you solve your problem? You should post it as an answer so that 1) it can help the next person with the same problem, and 2) so the question can be marked as solved.

Comment: @ikegami All the servers(servers in server) which were already there, are running properly. I am not able to do anything new. The problem persists as stated above in my question.

Comment: So your Perl installation is broken, but you want to fix it without changing it?

Comment: @ikegami I can do anything which will not harm existing servers.

Comment: You'll have to decide what has a smaller risk of causing harm: Doing nothing and continuing to operate with a corrupted installation of Perl and pray the resulting problems are caught before they cause harm, or fix the corrupted installation of Perl.

Comment: Please tell me how to fix this.